# Paris-Traceroute and Traceroute Difference

Tags: computer-networks, network-flow

I am trying to understand the difference between Paris-traceroute and normal traceroute.

I am using this website ( https://paris-traceroute.net/about) and trying to get the idea, what is Paris-traceroute trying to achieve.

If I understand correctly,original traceroute does not care about the flow that is assigned by the load balancers, which is something that Paris-traceroute is trying to solve, so all the probes that are hashed the same way by the load balancers would follow the same path.

However, I don't understand how does that work in the case of UDP. Image at the bottom of the page mentions that Load-Balancers just use Source port and Destination Port in case of UDP, and Paris-Traceroute is trying to use Checksum to navigate same probes through the same path/flow.

**Questions:**

1) If load balancers only use Source Port and Destination Port, where is the checksum even used? Is it assuming that we should add Checksum to the identification mechanism of each flow? In summary, is it assuming that Load Balancers now use Source Port, Destination Port and Checksum to identify a flow?

2) I don't understand how Traceroute is incrementing a Destination Port, which seems to be claimed on this website. Why would it do that?